# Angular HttpClient Return Type

Tags: angular, typescript

- `HttpClient.get<Response>()`
  returns `Observable<HttpEvent<Response>>`, right?
- `HttpClient.get<Response>().subscribe`
  returns `HttpEvent<Response>`, correct?
- `Response` is an array. But I can't use `array.prototype` methods

if my statements above are correct, should I use `any` type assertion to fix error?
or use re-type casting in `subscribe` for using generic?

**ADDED and EDITED**:

```
export class Test {
    constructor(public httpClient: HttpClient) {
    }

    get<T>(path: string, option?): Observable<T> {
        // Observable<HttpEvent<T>> is not assignable to type Observable<T>
        return this.httpClient.get<T>(path, option);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `Response` is an array? Don't you have to force a conversion with `as any[]` for instance?

Comment: many methods are passing generics, but assistant are display correct type.

Answer (score 8):

To get array intellisense :

```
myMethod(): Observable<MyClass[]> {
  return this.http.get<MyClass[]>('url');
}
```

Comment: `Observable<HttpEvent<T>>` is wrong? or is it different with `type MyClasses = MyClass[]`?

Comment: but, it would works only if the response is the array of objects

Comment: @styliss stop using `HttpEvent`. This is used in the interceptors, not in the http requests. As for Pavel, I infered that he is indeed receiving an array, since he asked to have intellisense for arrays. And if you strongly type a method, then yes, you should expect your endpoint to send the correct values. If it doesn't, then don't type it.

Comment: @trichetriche, but `HttpClient` methods are return `Observable<HttpEvent<T>>`, not `Observable<T>`, may i need to stop the wrapper method for `HttpClient`?

Comment: The signature of a `get` call is `get<T>(url: string, options?: {...}): Observable<T>`. So **stop using `HttpEvent` and cope with the actual signature of an HTTP call**.

Comment: (so to answer you, no, `HttpClient` methods don't return `HttpEvent`s).

Comment: @trichetriche, sorry, see the added codes, my editor tells error about my comment.

Comment: `protected httpClient` becomes `this.httpEvent` : no wonder it doesn't work.

Comment: @trichetriche, it is work fine without type. and `public` is same with `protected`, I tried changed.

Comment: ... Look at the name of your variables, you're not using the same one ...

Comment: @trichetriche, It was little mistake, The problem does not change.

Comment: If the problem doesn't change, then provide a [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: @trichetriche I hope the example matches the link. that's all. you told `HttpEvent<T>` does not return, but why return HttpEvent!?

Comment: I assume English isn't your first language, but please make complete sentences, this is very hard for me to understand you. And I didn't return `HttpEvent`, you did. I'm telling you to stop doing that.

Comment: @trichetriche you genius! I can't something do for language. other people does not using the generic for in `subscriber`? anyway I found reason from `httpClient.get`. `httpClient.request('get')` does not return `Observable<HttpEvent<T>>`

Comment: @trichetriche you're right if my question was about `HttpClient.request <T>`, But it was not. :p bye

Comment: Yeah sure whatever. Just delete your question, as it won't help anyone else but you.

Answer (score 1):

If you get an array of objects use `Interfaces`, like:

```
export interface Resp {
  prop1: any;
  prop2: any;
  ...
}
```

and use it as the return type on `.get` like:

```
return this.http.get<Resp[]>('url');
```

But if you have array of values, probably would be better to use `any`:

```
return this.http.get<any[]>('url');
```

Comment: yeah, is it return `Observable<HttpEvent<Resp[]>>` right?

Comment: @styliss yes, then in the component you may to subscribe the returned array to your Angular array or map to array of objects like service.myMethod().subscribe(resp => {this.myArray = resp})